# Autofill with NULL value add when the dropdown list didn't select anything

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to fill a textbox with NULL value when they is no data select on the dropdown list. Here some code that I'm using but still didn't know what should I add for this problem. Any idea?

Example:

```
function ew_AjaxAutoFill(obj) {

if (ewLang.isString(obj))
    obj = ew_GetElements(obj);
var ar = ew_GetOptValues(obj);
var id = ew_GetId(obj);
var sf = document.getElementById("sf_" + id);
if (ar.length < 1 || ar[0] == "" || !sf || sf.value == "")
    return;
var ds = new ewUtil.XHRDataSource(EW_LOOKUP_FILE_NAME);
ds.responseSchema.recordDelim = EW_RECORD_DELIMITER;
ds.responseSchema.fieldDelim = EW_FIELD_DELIMITER;
ds.responseType = ewUtil.DataSourceBase.TYPE_TEXT;
ds.maxCacheEntries = 0; 
var f = function(oRequest, oParsedResponse) {
    var aResults = oParsedResponse.results;
    var id = ew_GetId(this);
    var dn = document.getElementById("ln_" + id);
    var destNames = (dn) ? dn.value : "";
    var dest_array = destNames.split(",");
    var destEl, asEl, dfv;
    for (var j=0; j < dest_array.length; j++) {
        destEl = ew_GetElements(dest_array[j]);
        if (destEl && j < aResults[0].length) {
            dfv = aResults[0][j];
            if (destEl.options || destEl.length) {
                ew_SelectOpt(destEl, ar);
            } else if (destEl.type == "hidden") {
                asEl = ew_GetElements("sv_" + dest_array[j]);
                if (asEl) {
                    destEl.value = ar[0];
                    asEl.value = dfv;
                } else {
                    destEl.value = dfv;
                }
            } else if (destEl.type == "textarea") {
                destEl.value = dfv;
                if (typeof ew_UpdateDHTMLEditor == "function")
                    ew_UpdateDHTMLEditor(dest_array[j]);
            } else {
                destEl.value = dfv;
            }
        }
    }
}
var sQuery = "?q=" + encodeURIComponent(ar[0]) + "&s=" + sf.value;
ds.sendRequest(sQuery, f, obj);
}
```

Comment: Fill a textbox with a null value? That seems weird to me. Clearify your question and maybe strip down the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Set a default value in your drop-down list. For that default value, clear the content of the textfield:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('myArea').innerHTML=this.value">
  <option value=''> ----- </option>
  <option value='Yes'> Yes </option>
  <option value='Yes'> No </option>
</select>
<textarea id='myArea'></textarea>
```

It is important for you to accept no whitespaces beetween the 2 textarea. Otherwise, non-null values can be sent.